# "npm watch" command not working, but "npm run watch" command is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, watchify

Its said that `npm start` and `npm run start` are same, then in my case `npm run watch` is working fine but `npm watch` is not working,

Following is the error when i run `npm watch` is:

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\erdiv\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.13.4 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "watch": "npx watchify ./public/main.js -o ./public/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "budo": "^11.6.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Please help in clarification, that why can't i use command "npm watch" in this case.

Comment: npm start is an exception, like npm test. Your custom scripts must be called with `npm run`, not just `npm`.

Comment: and what is different in my script that i had to use `npm run` not just `npm` for running watchify? whereas its working fine with just `npm start` for running server.js.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) state: _"`run[-script]` is used by the **`test`**, **`start`**, **`restart`**, and **`stop`** commands, but can be called directly, as well."_ - Essentially the four aforementioned script names/keys may be invoked via the command line without (or with) the `run` keyword. E.g. `npm start` or `npm run start`, `npm test` or `npm run test` etc. Typically those four script names/keys are invoked without using the `run` keyword. However, any other script names/keys must utilize the `run` keyword. E.g. `npm run watch`, `npm run foobar`, etc...